# How can i use css with rails and the asset pipeline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I followed the guide but can't apply styles.

How can I make the page background blue?

I have the following file: `app/assets/stylesheets/main.css.scss`

Contents are: `body { background-color: #123456;}`

I have the following in my `app/assets/application.css.scss` file:

```
/*
 *
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree .
 */
```

The web page, once loaded includes the following line in the head tag:

```
<link href="/assets/main.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

But my webpage is not blue so I am ;)

How do I get the webpage background-color to be blue?

I've stopped and started the server to try and make sure that asset compilation is taking place.

Comment: When you inspect the styles of your body tag (with firefox or chrome dev tools), is your background color overrided by other styles?

Comment: Why is your SCSS asset named `application.css.scss` when you try to access `main.css`?

Comment: application.css.scss requires main.css.scss.

Comment: I don't think you have to rename the manifest file `application.css` by prefixing with `.scss`. It seems very strange to me why you have `main.css` in your source , it should be `application.css ` . Check for `stylesheet_include_tag "application.css"` in your layout view.

Answer (score 0):

Your css link needs to reference application.css - that is the main file name that the rest of the css is compiled into.

```
<link href="/application.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

also, in rails it's preferred to use the asset helpers:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application" %>
```

See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html for more documentation.

Comment: This is not necessarily true. In dev mode by default it does not combine the files into one.

Comment: right, but it's the entry point that starts the process of including all the other files included by the manifest.